# JavaScript forEach with selector -- functional replacement for JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, foreach, lodash, predicate

I wrote the following code recently:

```js
function genBoard(width, height, numMines) {
  let mineField = _.shuffle(Array(numMines).fill('*').concat(Array(width*height - numMines).fill(0)));
  mineField.forEach((elem, pos) => {
    if (elem == '*') {
      let blastArea = [pos-width-1, pos-width, pos-width+1, pos-1, pos+1, pos+width-1, pos+width, pos+width+1];
      blastArea.filter(p => p>=0 && p<width*height && mineField[p] != '*').forEach(p => mineField[p] += 1);
    }
  });
  _.chunk(mineField, width).forEach(row => console.log(row.join('')));
}
```

Note that I'm using `_.shuffle` and `_.chunk` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4%20lodash).

I'd like to do this in as functional a way as possible.  So I'd like the middle part to be more like this:

```js
mineField.forEachFiltered((elem, pos) => {
  let blastArea = [pos-width-1, pos-width, pos-width+1, pos-1, pos+1, pos+width-1, pos+width, pos+width+1];
  blastArea.filter(p => p>=0 && p<width*height && mineField[p] != '*').forEach(p => mineField[p] += 1);
  },
  elem => elem == '*'
);
```

In other words, the `forEachFiltered` takes two functions (instead of `forEach` taking one), where the second function is a selector, or you could call it a predicate.  If you examine the code you'll see that I can't conveniently use a combination of `forEach` and `filter` as I need to know my position in the original array.  I have tried googling but haven't found any notion of `forEachFiltered` anywhere, and also not in lodash.  Do I have to write that function or is there another way (or just use the `if` statement)?

P.S.: Example output with values 10, 6, 24:

```
*2233222**
32****3*6*
312445*5**
5322*4*5**
***22*35**
432112*3*3
```

P.P.S.:  To ask my question in the simplest possible way, how do you do `["my", "array", "of", "whatever"].forEach(func, selector)` ?

Comment: There's a bug in your code: It will increment the number of adjacent mines at `mineField[pos+1]` even if `pos` is at the end of a row, and likewise `mineField[pos-1]` if `pos` is at the beginning of a row.

Comment: Maybe he wanted the minefield to be a tube. ;) Either way I think we can ignore that aspect; it doesn't affect the possible solutions.

Comment: crap, definitely didn't want that :)  ... am trying to be clever instead of using a mountain of for loops.

Comment: With lodash's `filter` the second argument to the predicate is the index.

Comment: @GruffBunny -- yes, but even Array.prototype.filter() has that capability.  It's not enough.  Because I would need to get a filtered array, then run forEach on that, and during that traversal I'd need to know the position that the element held in the _original_ array.  So my use case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be fairly trivial to write your own implementation of `forEachFiltered`, based on the [polyfill for `Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEachFiltered', {
    value: function (func, predicate, thisArg) {
        var array = Object(this),
            index = 0,
            length = array.length >>> 0,
            value;

        while (index < length) {
            if (index in array) {
                value = array[index];
                if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, index, array)) {
                    func.call(thisArg, value, index, array);
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
});
```

Or you could implement it as just a wrapper for `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEachFiltered', {
    value: function (func, predicate, thisArg) {
        this.forEach(function () {
            if (predicate.apply(this, arguments)) {
                func.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }, thisArg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, I did notice that polyfill in the MDN doc you link to; using that as a template is a classy way to implement this function, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen any javascript libraries with iteration functions that work like you suggest (by taking a predicate function in addition to the normal function). Common Lisp, on the other hand, has functions like `substitute-if` (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sbs_s.htm#substitute-if) which are similar (and in fact have several optional arguments which further refine their behavior), but even so it doesn't have anything quite like your `forEachFiltered` function. For one thing, the Common Lisp iterator functions don't pass in any positions at all, unlike the JS ones.

Anyway, in your specific case I would say that you could `map` over the board to produce a list of objects that each represent a cell, containing the contents of the cell along with the cell's coordinates in the minefield. You can then `filter` that to produce a list of only those cells which have mines, and use `forEach` on that to compute the adjacencies. This is not quite like using the `forEachFiltered` functions you're contemplating, but allows you to do what you want. You may object that passing the coordinates around like that feels weird, and indeed it might be. I would say however that it's exactly the dual to the nested loops you started with.

Another alternative would be to write iteration functions that mimic Javascript's native iteration methods, but which pass you generalized n-dimensional coordinates when you iterate over an n-dimensional array. That would be a nice little library to have.

Comment: Yeah, I was betting this would be a no-brainer for LISP and descendants.

Comment: Well, I don't quite say that. The list iterator functions such as `mapc` (equivalent to Javascript's `forEach`) and `mapcar` (equivalent to `map` in JS) don't provide any information about the position at all, just the value out of the list.